# Can a connection be moved or shared between indy components?

Tags: delphi, binary, connection, indy

Is it possible to transfer a connection between indy components in delphi: to have a client thread connect, and then make server's onexecute event process this connection, rather than the thread? If it is, some syntax hints pls. Thank you.

Comment: Whats your mean of "Connection" ?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Maybe my choice of words is wrong. I have a lengthy serverExecute routine which collects data from a wireless sensor network (using indy 10 / delphi 2010 tcp server). Now I need to initiate the connection myself in some cases (with all the protocol being the same), and I guess I need to modify the code to fit a client thread. Trying to see if that can be avoided. This is my first indy application and i'm not expert in high level stuff.

Comment: @miodrag sounds like you just need to refactor your existing code so it can be called by both a server thread and a client thread, with a `TIdIOHandler` as input, then you can call it with `TIdContext.Connection.IOHandler` and `TIdTCPClient.IOHandler`, respectively.

Comment: K, thx, I'll fix it somehow. Btw, didn't take me long to figure these two are not completely parelel - client's iohandler requires CheckForDataOnSource for InputBuffer.Size and InputBufferIsEmpty to work, whereas server's iohandler provides these values "free of charge". Perhaps some setting i overlooked? Not like it matters, just curious.